# How to query mongodb sharding and replica set configuration from remote machine?

Tags: mongodb, configuration, sharding

I have to query to get mongodb cluster configuration from remote machine through programming code. I can get these details from mongo shell using sh.status() and rs.status() command. I am looking for a way to get similar details through REST API or any other way so I can detect the cluster setup with minimum user inputs through code. I have searched on internet but not getting any help. I am a beginner in mongodb area so please help me to resolve this requirement.

Comment: What are you actually asking here? When you say *"detect cluster setup"* then what is your intent? Unless you were building some kind of management tool then any normal application should not need to know such information. If you were then you would not be asking about a REST API. MongoDB drivers are self aware of shard and replica set members by themselves, and that is the software you should be using. If you are just asking for a recommended REST API built by someone else, then that is off-topic here.

Comment: As per my understanding, we need to provide config file or shard/replica set members list to MongoDB driver to create the client object. I have to make it automated. I am thinking rather taking all members details from user, we will just take router server details and fetch remaining details through program before creating the client object. mongo shell sh.status() and rs.status() commands are useful for it, but not getting how to get these details through program code. Please let me know.

Comment: Again, you are asking about database configuration,which is not a programming related question. Ask on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead.